# Error when running anchor test - rust directory not found

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana

On running the command `anchor test` it keeps returning an error.

`error: not a directory: '/home/dhruv/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.18.2/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/rust/bin'`

However, in the location `/home/dhruv/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.18.2/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/rust/` there only a `lib` folder in there.

I have uninstalled and re-installed it multiple times.
Cleared all possible caches, the error keeps persisting.

installed using `rustup`, using the stable toolchain, I can run

- `rustc --version` successfully
- `cargo --version` successfully
- `solana --version` successfully
- `avm --version` successfully
- `anchor --version` successfully
  I can even run the `solana-test-validator`
  Totally blocked on this one. Not understanding how to solve this.

Adding my PATH variable
`/home/dhruv/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:/home/dhruv/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/home/dhruv/.nvm/versions/node/v21.6.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dhruv/Android/Sdk/emulator:/home/dhruv/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/dhruv/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/dhruv/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/dhruv/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:/home/dhruv/.cargo/bin:/home/dhruv/.avm/bin`

**What should the solana file structure look like after a proper install? Where is the `bin` folder located?**

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix was to delete everything in the folder `/home/<USER>/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.18.2/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/`
and then run `anchor test` again.

I saw this error with other colleagues as well - the error occurs due to improper unpacking of the tar file in `platform-tools`.
You could also try manually unpacking the tar file again.